# Design for chats between users

Tags: laravel, database-design

I have 3 models: `Events`, `groups` and `users`.

Relations:

Events - Users - many to many.
Groups - Users - many to many.

There will be one chat withing group and one inside event. I am going to implement chats between two or more users. What is the best way to design it? I created Chat model and many to many relation between chat and users.

First idea: The members of group and event chats will be stored in respectively `event_users` and `group_users` tables. Only chats between users will be stored in `chat_users`.

Second idea: `chat_users` will be synchronized with `event_users` and `group_users` tables. The advantage is separated logic to manage chats and there will be not many complicated queries.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that `Chat` has a polymorphic association with `Group` and `Event` (and maybe `User` as well). Some solutions to the problem are provided here:
https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql/29-Polymorphic_Assocations_Solutions_Exclusive_arcs

Could something like this work?

**ChatUser**

- id
- user_id
- chat_id

**Chat (exclusive arcs method)**

- id
- event_id (nullable)
- group_id (nullable)
- description/etc

**ChatMessage**

- id
- chat_id
- user_id_from
- user_id_to (nullable)
- date
- message

Assumptions made:

- event/group can contain multiple chats
- user can belong to a group but not to group chat

Besides, Laravel comes with a native polymorphic relation handling solution. It could fit here as well.

Answer (score 1):

User can participate to an event and event can have many users who participate to that event, in this specific case we need to use as Many to Many relation [Laravel One to Many Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

**event_user**

- id
- event_id
- user_id

User can be member of many group and a group can avec many member, in this case we need a Many to Many relation [Laravel Many to Many Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

**group_user**

- id
- group_id
- user_id

chat can be related to an event or a group, so we save the type of the chat witch can be either Event or Group and the corresponding ID of that event or group. so if we have a particular chat we can retreive all users related to that chat through the corresponding event or group it depending of the chatable_type in each case, to learn more see [Laravel Many To Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

**chats**

- id
- name
- chatable_id
- chatable_type

we need also one table to save all conversations for specific chat

**messages**

- id
- chat_id
- message
- created_at

and for users chat you can create a separate table witch can save the related information about that chat specifiquely

**conversations**

- id
- sender_id
- receiver_id
- message

all sender_id and receiver_id will be foreign key witch reference some id on users table